# issue with Collapsible Set on icon in JQuery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

How can  I do collapsible set on icon? This is my icon code.

```
<div id="custom-border-radius">
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-plus ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all">No text</a>
</div>
```

On click of '+' icon i need to show and hidd list ( Send SMS and Send Mail), code is as follows,

```
<input type="submit" id="sms" data-inline="true" value="Send SMS">
<input type="submit" id="mail" data-inline="true" value="Send Mail">
```

How can i do that with collapsible concept. Is there other way, Any suggestions please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div data-role="collapsible" id='collapsible1'>
    <h4>Heading</h4>
    <form>
    <input type="button" data-inline="true" id='btn1' value="Input">
    <div class="ui-input-btn ui-btn ui-btn-inline">
        Enhanced
        <input type="button" data-enhanced="true" id='btn2' value="Enhanced">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
<script>
$('#btn1').click(function(){
    alert("Btn 1 clicked");
    document.getElementById('collapsible1').style.display = 'none';
});
$('#btn2').click(function(){
    alert("Btn 2 clicked");
    document.getElementById('collapsible1').style.display = 'none';
});
</script>
```

Edited to add disappearing behavior to the collapsible set
JFiddle is here [(Demo)](http://jsfiddle.net/xFLVe/1/)

Comment: It is working fine, Is there any way to hide collapsible set on click of anywhere in htnl page ?

Comment: Sure. I edited the answer. The key is to add an id to the collapsible div and call this in your .click function document.getElementById('divname').style.display = 'none';